# "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" while opening user profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

I can't seem to get to [my user profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema). It was working 5 minutes ago. The rest of the web site seems fine.

Ideas?

Comment: I see this too. This is related to the activity's tab in profiles, I don't know the details, try it on my profile. Here is the MSE question for more info https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348987/opening-my-own-profile-page-causes-a-something-bad-happened-error

Comment: Seems fixed now?

Comment: @MarkKirby Yup. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

This was reported on MSE:

- [Opening my own profile page causes a "Something bad happened!" error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348987/707129)

It is reported to now be fixed:

> We pushed a change out that was behind a feature flag. Unfortunately, we missed a page that needed to check for that setting...the profile page.